# Remove np.nan from a pd.DataFrame index

Tags: python, pandas, select, nan

I have a dataframe with accident data of some streets:

[image: street accident data]

I'd like to remove (or at least select) that first row that is indexed as `np.nan`. I tried `streets.loc[np.nan,:]` but that returns a `KeyError: nan`. I'm not sure how else to specifically select that record.

Other than using `pd.DataFrame.iloc[0,:]` (which is imprecise as it relies on location rather than index name) how can I select that specific record?

Answer (score 1):

I think there are two options you can do.

1. You can fill any random value to nan and then select it.

   df.fillna(value={'ON STREET NAME': 'random'})
   streets.loc['random',:]
2. assign another index column, but this can affect your dataframe later.

Answer (score 1):

You can do `df = df.dropna()`

This will remove all rows with at least one `nan` value.

Optionally, you could also do `df.dropna(inplace=True)` The parameter `inplace` just means that you don't have to specify `df = df.dropna()` and it will modify the original var for you.

You can find more info on this here: [pandas.DataFrame.dropna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html)

Answer (score 0):

I will do

```
df = df[df.index.notna()]
```

Comment: Could you explain your solution?